# Setting border on scrollable HTML frame

Tags: html, css, scroll, border, frames

I have a frame that will host a navigation tree. I want to have a blue border on the right side of the frame. This border should fill the entire frame area from top to bottom and the frame should also be scrollable.

The frame has no fixed size, it will fill the entire left side of the browser window and will change size when the user resizes the browser window.

The tree frame (and a minimal context) is defined as:

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<frameset cols="250,*" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" >  
    <frame src="tree.html" scrolling="auto" /> 
    <frame src="about:blank" name="navTarget" scrolling="auto" /> 
</frameset>
</html>
```

In the frame content (tree.html) I define the border as:

```
<style type="text/css">
    html {
        border-right: red 2px solid;
        background: yellow;
    }
</style>
```

Now, if the tree content is large enough to fill the frame area (or larger, in which case scrollbars are automatically added) then this works well.

However, if the tree is "too small" and does not expand to fill the entire frame area, then the border will not fill the entire right side of the frame, but stop partway down.

[image: Tree content does not will the frame]

UPDATE: This seems to be browser specific. In Firefox 8 and Opera 11 the content border is cut short, but in Chrome it fills the whole right frame border.

That can in turn be fixed forcing the tree to expand to the available area:

```
<style type="text/css">
    html {
        height: 100%;
        border-right: blue 2px solid;
        background:yellow;
    }
</style>
```

But in this case when the tree is large enough to require scrolling you will notice that the border disappears when you scroll down. At least in modern browsers like IE8+, Firefox, Chrome and Opera. In IE6 the border will stay in place when scrolling for some reason.

[image: Border disappers when scrolling down]

UPDATE: This fails (i.e. border disappers when scrolling) in all of Chrome, Firefox and Opera.

Is there a simple way to make it work as I want to also in other browsers?

The background on the other hand works as expected, it will fill the entire frame area in all cases, so why not the border?

**SOLUTION:**

The solution finally found was to set the border on the BODY element instead of HTML as well as setting HTML element height to 100% and BODY element min-height to 100%.

Using min-height for BODY instead of height ensures that the border does not disappear when scrolling and that it does fill the entire border for "too short" contents.

```
<style type="text/css">
    html { height:100%; }
    body { min-height:100%; }
    body { border-right:blue 2px solid; }
</style>
```

Since IE6 does not support min-height we use plain height for it. Which happens to work in that browser (border does not disappear when scrolling), but not in more modern ones.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
body { height:100%; }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: can't you add the `border` style not to inner html page but the iframe?

Comment: "But in this case when the tree is large enough to require scrolling you will notice that the border disappears when you scroll down" --> I just think the scrollbar overlaps your right borders. But this statement makes me confused. The border only disappears when scrolling down ?

Comment: "The border only disappears when scrolling down" Yes, before you start scrolling it fills the entire right side of the frame content, but the parts of the content down below that becomes visible when you scroll down do not have a border for some reason. I guess this is because the border is created from the "height: 100%" which will be the size of the hosting frame. So only for the visible area of the content and not the whole scrollable area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup.  As @Zoltan Toth said, add the styles to the iframe itself... (you may also need a frameborder="0" attribute in some browsers, and you'll want to do:

**UPDATED:**

In tree.html styles:

```
body { border:0; border-right: 2px solid blue; min-height: 400px; /* change this */ }
```

In referencing document:

```
<iframe src="tree.html" frameborder="0" style="border:0; width:400px; height:400px; "></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it seems that does not quite work. When you apply border-right style to the frame it is placed on the wrong side of the scrollbar (when that is visible); I want it left of the scrollbar, not the right. So it seems the border must be defined in the frame content and not on the frame itself.

Comment: I don't think it will work to specify a fixed height for the frame as that does not suit the requirements. I'm not using an iframe, but a normal frame inside a frameset. I've edited the question to make that clearer. Though if nothing else works maybe min-height (even if it does not seem to work in IE6 ) could be used to make it a little better at least. Have to be careful that the chosen value is not too large and cause unnecessary scrollbars to appear I guess.

Comment: In that case, I'd do a repeating background image on your tree.html page.  Just a 2px wide by 1px tall blue .gif, repeat-y

Comment: Well, what do you see, using a css background image did the trick. Thanks for that tip! I ended up with this CSS "html, #idTreeContainer {
 background-image:url('images/tree_border.png');
 background-repeat:repeat-y;
 background-position:right top;
}
". Had to specify it on the tree container as well for some reason. If I did that for border-right I got double borders, but not for the background image. Well, as long as it works! (Though a solution not using a hack like this would be preferable, having a separate image to maintain and possibly also update later is not ideal.)

Comment: Sure.  If you wanted to simply change the color or width, it would be difficult.  But given your other requirements (unknown height, no unnecessary scrollbar, etc.), this seems the least hackish ;). Glad it worked.

Comment: After reading this page (http://phrogz.net/css/htmlvsbody.html) and getting to understand the relationship between html and body elements better, I actually did manage to come up with a less hackish solution. But that was also thanks to your min-height suggestion! I'll add an answer of my own for this.

Comment: Great! Sustainable solutions, ftw.